# Handling for spinner on orientation change - android

Tags: android-spinner, orientation-changes

I have spinner in my activity. When spinner is clicked, drop-down is shown.
Now, Change orientation. That drop-down is not maintained.
Is there any way to shown drop-down again on orientation change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear to me.

Please try adding this to your `<activity>` in your android manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

[See this for details](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

(Some might say this is not the *right way* to do it, but you can use this until you find a better solution)

Comment: This solution is not the correct way to go about this problem. The best way would be to get the value of the selected index in `onSaveInstanceState` and save it to the `Bundle` then restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState`. If you have a listener - set this after you've updated the value so that it isn't constantly triggered across orientation changes (unless, of course this is what you want).